# How to put inline R code inside R Markdown grid table?

Tags: r, r-markdown, beamer

I have the following Rmarkdown MWE. I compile it with beamer:

````
---
title: "Test"
output:
  beamer_presentation
---

# Test

## Hi

```{r, include=FALSE}
a=1
b=2
c=3
d=4
```

+-----+----------+---------+
|     | Treated  | Control |
+=====+==========+=========+
|age  | `r a`    | `r c`   |
|educ | `r b`    | `r d`   |
+-----+----------+---------+
````

The result is this: the table is not formatted properly

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your suggested table works even without the inline R code chunks?

Comment: no I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

EDITED to correct:

There are lots of different ways to produce tables in Markdown, and the one you chose isn't convenient when
R code is included, because the vertical bars need to line
up *after* the code is replaced by its expansion.

In your example the expansions are a single character, so for example, the five characters `'r a'` will be replaced by just one, and that will mess up the alignment.  You could add four blanks and it would almost work, but there's another problem in your example:  with that format, you need to put in separators between every pair of lines.  So this works:

```
+-----+----------+---------+
|     | Treated  | Control |
+=====+==========+=========+
|age  | `r a`        | `r c`       |
+-----+----------+---------+
|educ | `r b`        | `r d`       |
+-----+----------+---------+
```

but it won't work if you change any of the variables to have 2 digits.  This is inconvenient (and ugly too!), so I don't recommend using that kind of table in R Markdown.  (Previously I incorrectly said it wasn't supported; in fact it is, but it's still pretty useless.)

A couple of alternatives:

- Use `knitr::kable()` to produce your table, e.g.

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
tab <- cbind(c(a, b), c(c, d))
rownames(tab) <- c("age", "educ")
colnames(tab) <- c("Treated", "Control")
knitr::kable(tab, booktabs = TRUE)
```
````

- Use the same formatting as `kable` uses:

```
|     | Treated| Control|
|:----|-------:|-------:|
|age  | `r a`  |  `r c` |
|educ | `r b`  |  `r d` |
```

Comment: (1) How is the kable syntax called, and where do I find the docs for it? (2) why it doesn't work for my table? are there other tables for which it would work?

Comment: I think that `md_extensions` is only for [HTML document](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#markdown-extensions)